# Why does this if statement test not work?

Tags: java, file, sorting, if-statement, filter

I am comparing a user input to a given file input: [Input file](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse142/14au/homework/names.txt)

If the parsed user input token matches the parsed file input tokens, then the file input is returned as a String.

```
public static String findMatch(Scanner input, String name, String gender){
    String output = "";
    boolean fileContains = false;
    String fileName = "";
    String fileGender = "";
    System.out.println("User input = " + name + " " + gender);
    while (input.hasNextLine() && (fileContains == false)) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        Scanner scanLine = new Scanner(line);
        if(line.toUpperCase().contains(name.toUpperCase()) && line.contains(gender.toUpperCase())){
            fileName = scanLine.next();
            fileGender = scanLine.next();
            System.out.println("File input = " + fileName + " " + fileGender);
        }

        if (name.equals(fileName.toUpperCase()) && gender.equals(fileGender.toUpperCase())) {
            fileContains = true;
            System.out.println("The user input matches the file input.");
            output = line;
        }
    } 
    //exit out of while loop
    System.out.println("fileContains no longer is false.");
    System.out.println(output);
    return output;
}
```

The problematic if statement is here:

```
        if (name.equals(fileName.toUpperCase()) && gender.equals(fileGender.toUpperCase())) {
            fileContains = true;
            System.out.println("The user input matches the file input.");
            output = line;
        }
```

How the arguments name and gender are obtained:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = getName(console);
    String gender = getGender(console);
    String check = find(input, name, gender);
}
public static String getName(Scanner console) {
    System.out.print("name? ");
    return console.next();
}

public static String getGender(Scanner console) {
    System.out.print("gender (M or F)? ");
    return console.next();
}
```

I have attempted printing the file input and the user input and they are both clearly the same. I am not sure why it is not working.

User input: Jane F

**Expected output:**

User input = Jane F

File input = Janette F

File input = Janessa F

File input = Maryjane F

File input = Anjanette F

File input = Janeen F

File input = Janell F

File input = Jane F

The user input matches the file input.

fileContains no longer is false.

Jane F 98 108 128 116 48 55 47 39 67 202 312 345 436 384

**Actual Output**:

User input = Jane F

File input = Janette F

File input = Janessa F

File input = Maryjane F

File input = Anjanette F

File input = Janeen F

File input = Janell F

File input = Jane F

File input = Janey F

File input = Janelle F

File input = Janel F

File input = Janene F

File input = Janet F

fileContains no longer is false.

Comment: "have attempted printing the file input and the user input and they are both clearly the same". Show us the values. Because "clearly", they're not.

Comment: Saying something "doesn't work" is a no-no on StackOverflow; we need to know just **how** it's not working--what output you expect and what you're getting instead, for instance.

Comment: If your `if` condition that tests `contains` is `false`, then instead of setting `fileName` and `fileGender`, those variables will remain however they were set last time through the `while` loop.  In that case, you probably should _not_ be using those leftover values in your next `if` statement.  That bug appears to be harmless in this case, but in a different case it could make the program incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, I will illustrate the expected output and the actual output in my post. One moment.

Comment: You've given us the user input, but we can't see what the actual `name` and `gender` arguments to your method are, and we can't see the code that calls it to see how it computes those arguments.  So there's still a very important missing piece of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `name.equals(fileName.toUpperCase())` you should use either `name.equals(fileName)` or `name.equalsIgnoreCase(fileName)` depending on what you want. The same goes for `gender`.

Comment: .toUpperCase() is added so the case of user input is ignored.

Comment: One of the necessary requirements for this program is that the user should be able to enter in jane, Jane, JANE, JanE, or whatever variation they choose as long and it will still compare and sort correctly.

Comment: @user3450277 This is the correct answer.  The problem is that when you do the comparison, you upper-case the name from the file but you don't upper-case the name that the user input.  So `equals` will return false.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the way you're invoking it, or in the arguments you're passing. The method you've posted works just fine.

Here's the entire file that I've just compiled and run:

```
package jah.tests.stackoverflow;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileRead {

    public static String findMatch(Scanner input, String name, String gender) {
        String output = "";
        boolean fileContains = false;
        String fileName = "";
        String fileGender = "";
        System.out.println("User input = " + name + " " + gender);
        while (input.hasNextLine() && (fileContains == false)) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            Scanner scanLine = new Scanner(line);
            if (line.toUpperCase().contains(name.toUpperCase())
                    && line.contains(gender.toUpperCase())) {
                fileName = scanLine.next();
                fileGender = scanLine.next();
                System.out.println("File input = " + fileName + " "
                        + fileGender);
            }

            if (name.equals(fileName.toUpperCase())
                    && gender.equals(fileGender.toUpperCase())) {
                fileContains = true;
                System.out.println("The user input matches the file input.");
                output = line;
            }
        }
        // exit out of while loop
        System.out.println("fileContains no longer is false.");
        System.out.println(output);
        return output;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        findMatch(new Scanner("names.txt"), "Randall", "M");
    }

}
```

and it gives me this output:

```
User input = Randall M
fileContains no longer is false.
```

Note that I haven't changed anything at all in your code.

If I change the last bit to

```
findMatch(new Scanner("names.txt"), "Jane", "F");
```

then this works too:

```
User input = Jane F
fileContains no longer is false.
```

Comment: When I attempt to use a case that I know is present in the code, for example, Jane F, it doesn't recognize the Jane F line in the file.

Comment: The String output doesn't change because the program, for some reason, doesn't recognize the similar outputs. I tried doing it a different way where I checked if the inputLine contained the user input, but that causes other bugs.

Comment: @user3450277 It works perfectly with `Jane` and `F`. I've just edited my answer to show this.

Comment: @user3450277 have you tried running my code without changing anything (except for package declaration)?

Comment: The output which you're describing actually doesn't coincide with what I'm trying to do, I think.

Comment: @user3450277 then you need to explain more what you're trying to do! It is working perfectly well for detecting whether the input matches a line in the file.

Comment: Sorry. Please see my post once more.

Answer (score 0):

This line looks suspicious.  You are comparing `line.toUpperCase()` for the name, but not for the gender.

```
if(line.toUpperCase().contains(name.toUpperCase()) && 
   line.contains(gender.toUpperCase()))
```

Did you mean?

```
if(line.toUpperCase().contains(name.toUpperCase()) && 
   line.toUpperCase().contains(gender.toUpperCase()))
```

Comment: That's definitely another bug I overlooked, thank you! Unfortunately, that doesn't solve the overall problem that I have.